# Freezing system for Arctic adventure

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, new-gm

I will soon DM my first Game. I've created an Arctic story and want to implement a homebrew Freezing mechanic. I want to make a "Freezing status" update about 3 - 5 times per in-game Day. Each character has a Freezing state. His Gear, his location and his current position have an effect on his state. If a character falls in negative state, the effects stated bellow fall on him.

[image]
[image]

Outside Source:
Small Open Lamp +1,
Torch   +2,
Small Campfire  +3,
Medium Fire Spell   +3,
Campfire    +3,
Large Campfire  +4,
Large Fire Spell    +4,
Bonfire +5

Activity:
Prone   -1,
Standing Still / Crouch +0,
Walking +1,
Running +2,
Swimming    - Loc Mod * 3,

Shelter:
Makeshift Shelter   +0,
Makeshift Isolated Shelter  +1,
Makeshift Blanket   +1,
Tent    +2,
Sleeping Bag    +2,
Unisolated House    +3,

Events and Special Locations:
Storm   -1,
Blizzard    -2,
Wet - Loc Mod * 2,
Cave 0m - -100m +1,
Cave -100m - -200m  -1,
Cave <-200m -2,
Mountain 0m - 100m  -1,
Mountain 100m - 200m    -2,
Mountain > 200m -3

[image]

I created this system because I want the players to consider their choice of clothes and equipment.

**How to use the System**
About 3-5 Times a day the DM calls for an freezing state update. Every player updates his values in the "Calculation" Tab. The "location Modifier" is determent by the location on the map. The circles and lines get added up. So if you stand in "Line -2" and in "Circle -3", you have a location modifier of -5. The Gear modifier is calculated by the Stats under "Gear". All items are added up. The "Outside source modifier" is determent by the current position of a character. E.G: in a blizzard, in a tent...
All those Numbers get added up. This is the "per turn" Modifier, Each time the dm calls for an update, the per turn modifier is added to the Freeze State. If the Freeze state is negative, the character will suffer effects similar to the

**Example**
A Ranger with average gear that is sleeping in a tent near "Kleinfarlond" during a storm will have a Freezing state of 3. So if he would remain in this position for a day, his freezing state would go up by about 9 - 15 Points. If he would fall in a lake and go back to the tent, his stat would be 1 because the location modifier would get doubled for being wet.

**Now my Question**:
Do you think that this system will be balanced for the map in the Picture or do you think that this system makes the weather to big of a problem. Also, do you have any input to improve the system?

We don't play strictly by the rules, so I don't think that introducing a homebrew system will bother any of the players

Comment: Looks like this question is better suited to interactive exploration than Q&A; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85652/discussion-on-question-by-bolphgolph-freezing-system-for-arctic-adventure).